# How to smoothly expand element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

By clicking "`#sidebarnav>li`" :
1)the second child of it - `<ul>` element will expand and its class toggles between `"collapse"` and `"collapse in"`

2)`"#sidebarnav>li"` gets "active" class.

3)"aria-expanded" attributes in `<a>` and `<ul>` tags become "true"

I want to expand ul elements smoothly when clicking its parent but I couldn't achieve that. Tried to add transition: `height 500ms ease-in-out` style to the class "`collapse in`" but won't work. So how to make it work?
Chek it out on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yno3kxrm/)

```
<!--language: lang-html-->
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="in" id="sidebarnav">
        <li> 
           <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
              <span class="hide-menu">Dashboard</span>
           </a>
           <ul class="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <li><a href="index.html">Minimal </a></li>
            <li><a href="index2.html">Analytical</a></li>
            <li><a href="index3.html">Demographical</a></li>
            <li><a href="index4.html">Modern</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: use jquery's slidedown function, here is how to https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot animate `height` with percentage values, so about the best you can do is use `transform`.

If you need an "expansion" effect you'll have to resort to using JavaScript. Here's how to use `transform`:

Surround the `ul` in a container:

```
<div class="collapse-container">
  <ul class="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    [...]
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hide overflow on the container so the `ul` doesn't overlap:

```
.collapse-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Animate the `translateY` on `.in`:

```
.collapse {
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.collapse.in {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

[Here's a working Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8wt63r7u/3/) (I changed the JS to work with the container element)